# Is it safe to pass a Lucene Query String directly from a user into a QueryParser?

Tags: spring-boot, security, lucene, hibernate-search

*tldr:* Can I *securely* pass a raw query string (retrieved as a URL parameter) into a Lucene QueryParser without any added input sanitization?

I'm not a security expert, but I need some advice. As the title states, is it safe to use this controller method:

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "${allowed-origin}")
    @GetMapping(value = "/search/{query_string}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List doSearch(@PathVariable("query_string") String queryString) {
        return searchQueryHandlerService.doSearch(queryString);
    }
```

In tandem with this service method (the error handling is for testing only):

```
    public List doSearch(String queryString) {
        LOGGER.debug("Parsing query string: " + queryString);
        try {
            Query q = new QueryParser(null, standardAnalyzer).parse(queryString);
            FullTextEntityManager manager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
            FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = manager.createFullTextQuery(q, Poem.class, Book.class, Section.class);
            return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

With only basic input sanitization? If this isn't safe are there measures I can take to make it safe?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've been looking into this on and off for the last few weeks and I cannot find any reason why it *wouldn't* be safe, but It's such an obscure question (in an area I'm unfamiliar with) that I may be missing some obvious, fundamental problem anyone working in the area would see immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *FullTextQuery* is always read only, so you don't have to be concerned with people dropping tables or similar issues that you might have to consider when dealing with SQL injection.

But you might want to be careful if you have security restrictions on what data can be seen by your users.

The API also restricts the operation to a certain set of indexes - in your case those containing the Poem entities - so it's also not possible to break out of the chosen indexes.

But you need to consider:

- is it ok if the user is able to somehow find a different Poem than what you expected them to look for
- if you share the same index with other entities, there might be some ways to infer data about these other entities

So to be security conscious you might want to:

- each entity type gets indexed into its own index (which is the default).
- enable some `FullTextFilter` to restrict the user query based on your custom rules.
- actually check the content of each result before rendering it, so to remove content that your other filters didn't catch.

If you are extremely paranoid, consider that any full-text index can actually reveal a bit about how frequent certain terms are in the whole index. People are normally not too concerned about this as it's extremely hard to take advantage of, and only minimal clues about the data distribution are revealed.

So back at your example, if this index just contains poems and you're ok with allowing any user to see any poem you have stored, giving away clues about which poems you are making available is normally not a security concern but is rather the whole point of your service.

Comment: This is perfect. I will need to segment the search results based on auth state, but looking into the FullTextFilter I don't think it will be difficult to simply create an 'authed user' endpoint and a 'public' endpoint to handle the different requirements. Thank you for this well written, thorough answer.